# Is subsonic dead?

Tags: subsonic, data-access-layer

The company I work for pretty much uses a subsonic DAL for everything we do.

I recently noticed that the [domain](http://subsonicproject.com/) was released.

So is subsonic dead?

Comment: [Rob already answered this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2038373/63733) himself more than two years ago:

Comment: two years ago, but now the domain is unpaided, and there are no screencast available, nether good help about subsonic. How anyone one can use it with out help or the steps to begin ?

Comment: after the big fail of version 3, that is really better to delete it because of the huge delay to fetch data, the version 2 is really a good DAL, but it dos not seems that they care to make version 2 better and keep it live - they stick with the 3 that is not worthing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363735/benchmark-linq2sql-subsonic2-subsonic3-any-other-ideas-to-make-them-faster

Comment: the real problem of subsonic 2 right now is that there aren't any help or screen cast to help you starts. So it going to be die soon and keeped only from some people that have build something on it all ready.

Comment: I just read the post. You are the only one saying so. Maybe subsonic is fading away. But why do you keep doing this ? A good open source developer might stop his work because of this kinda attitude

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is SubSonic dying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037051/is-subsonic-dying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all your info, the domain is back up (probably got lost in the flood of Rob's inbox).

I put a lot of time in Jan-Feb 2012 into fixing up all the outstanding bugs in SubSonic 2, including patching, fixing or removing a lot of the failing unit tests (there were quite a few), actioning outstanding pull requests, and generally giving it a good tune up.

I had also added an MS Access provider and an auto enum generator to it.

But SS2 is very much 'mature' now, and I can't see much happening to it apart from bug fixes. That said, now that the help resources are back up, it's still a great and complete package. If there's not much active patching, that may be because it doesn't need any.

SS3 takes the project in a very different direction. I'm happy using it, but as with all these things, I mainly concentrate on what I can do WITH it rather than the tool itself. There is a pretty big backlog of outstanding stuff on SS3, and I'm not up with or even that keen on LINQ, so not sure how I'd go trying to fix anything to do with that.

And Rob has moved on to Massive, his .NET 4 dynamic tool.

UPDATE: The actual official SubSonic site is at: subsonic.wekeroad.com

Subsonicproject.com is a secondary site previously registered by contributor Eric Kemp, fallen to domain sqatters, largely broken. I nearly fell over when Rob told me this.

Comment: Can I just add, reading the above you could get the impression that the tool is not complete and there are problems to fix. That is NOT true as far as I am aware, both work well, and there are quite substantial sites running both SS2 and SS3. What HAS happened is that users have submitted small updates and patches to fix various niche issues, and a lack of active maintenance on the project has cause these to accumulate. This, while not desirable, is actually not a major problem.

Comment: Update: Even the wekeroad site is broken now, leaving us without any definitive docs on the project. I and many others have moved on to PetaPoco, which uses the SubSonic templates but sidesteps the speed problems with SS3 and doesn't add LINQ (a plus in my view). So apart from all the legacy sites out there running it (I've got a few), and the fact that the GIT repo will give you a perfectly functional download of SS2 and SS3, it is pretty much dead now.

Answer (score 5):

The domain does seem dead.  Their [github repository](https://github.com/subsonic) is still online though, with most recent activity from a month ago.  The author Rob [has a blog](http://wekeroad.com/) but he doesn't seem to have addressed his poor domain, though he does seem to acknowledge that it hasn't seen much attention from him.

Answer (score 2):

YES!

Rest in peace, my old friend :(